# PostgresQL Help on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So when I try to make a database for my rails application I get the following:

```
nmsiriban:~/workspace/code/devcamp/DevCampPortfolio $ rails db:create
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"DevCampPortfolio_development"}
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I keep getting this error on both "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" Bash Shell and on the C9.io terminal shell

when I run

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

it says to use `pg_createcluster`

When I doI get this:

```
Nick@NICKS_LAPTOP:~$ sudo pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start
Creating new cluster 9.6/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.6/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main
  locale en_US.UTF-8
FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=56, 03600).
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main"
Error: initdb failed
```

And I am stuck here at this step. I have pgAdmin3 by BigSQL installed on my Windows machine and I have a it installed on a folder in my Windows OS with a symbolic link to my Linux Subsystem directory.

I am new to using Linux based systems such as Ubuntu and I have been doing a lot of googling. So if anyone needs more information please ask and I will do my best to supply what you need.

Comment: " Function not implemented" so WSL doesn't support that yet. File a feature request or something: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues

Comment: You'd be better off running the PostgreSQL server's native Windows version, and connecting to it from the dev env.

Comment: @CraigRinger how would I go about doing that? I've googled for a few hours already and all I get are tutorials on how to install PostgesQL natively on Windows or how to install on my UNIX console. I haven't found a tutorial yet that shows you how to connect the Windows version to a dev enviorment.

Comment: @NickSiriban It's just TCP/IP...

Comment: As @CraigRinger suggested running PostgreSQL on windows and connecting it from WSL should work. Detailed instructions, esp which all PS client libraries are to be installed on WSL, are listed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/61#issuecomment-266611925). Hope this helps.